# SQL - replace specific part of a string in multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to replace a specific part of a string with another?
E.g. I have a column which holds a path to a file, I renamed the folder **download portal** (on my physical harddrive) to **download_portal**, so I have to change the path in thousands of database records.

**Example record before and after:**

```
/fileadmin/download portal/test/myfile.jpg
```

after:

```
/fileadmin/download_portal/test/myfile.jpg
```

Let's assume this is my table **fruits**:

```
id | path
1  | /fileadmin/download portal/test/apple.jpg
2  | /fileadmin/download portal/test/banana.jpg
3  | /fileadmin/download portal/test/pineapple.jpg
```

How can I change `download portal` to `download_portal` in every record by using SQL? Can I solve it by using [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)?

Comment: read about replace funtion. Please add the dbms tag which you are using

Comment: [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you necessarily need a regex replacement here.  Just a normal replacement of `download portal` to `download_portal` should work.  The following `UPDATE` should work on most databases:

```
UPDATE fruits
SET path = REPLACE(path, '/download portal/', '/download_portal/')
WHERE path LIKE '%/download portal/%'
```

Note: I think searching for `/download portal/` is more restrictive, and safer, than just the plain text.  This is so because it eliminates the chance of accidentally replacing `download portal` which appears as part of some other larger path name.

Comment: That worked thx! I wonder If this would also work with regular expressioins.

Comment: If you're actually using MySQL, then the answer is no, because MySQL does not support regex replacement, at least not without writing your own user-defined function.  You got lucky, perhaps, because normal replacements should cover your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSMS you can use REPLACE Function to get what you want.

> Update tableName SET ColumnToChange = Replace(ColumnToChange,
>   'x_name','x_myname')